# Problem with delayed expansion and FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I made a password generator and currently trying to make it look as confusing as possible (by putting everthing on a line).
This is what it looks like right now (sorry if it's too hard to read):

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ERROR >%temp%\char1 & echo a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ERROR >%temp%\char2 & echo A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ERROR >%temp%\char3 & set count=0 & set count2=0 & set useSpecialChar=0 & set char=15 & (if !useSpecialChar!==1 (set rnd=62) else (set rnd=92))
:gen
(if %count%==%char% echo. & set /a count2+=1 & set count=0) & (if !count2!==5 pause >nul & set count2=0) & set /a c=%random%%%62+1 & set charno=1 & (if !c! gtr 10 set /a c-=10 & set charno=2) & (if !c! gtr 26 set /a c-=26 & set charno=3) & (for /f "tokens=%c% delims= " %%a in (%temp%\char%charno%) do (<nul set /p =%%a)) & set /a count+=1 & goto gen
```

When I try to run it, it *kinda* works:

```
 delims= " was unexpected at this time.
dx67ZujROJ1YSA
j0DoVFjQRTcZOhP
cmbAesdRnre9BFd
aBHCHOFEUxECQFK
bIDWKPixIf525pC
```

I think I got  `delims= " was unexpected at this time.` because of the `%c%` variable in `FOR` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=%c% delims= " %%a in (%temp%\char%charno%) do (<nul set /p =%%a)
```

Since I had `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, I tried replacing `%c%` with `!c!` but it got worse:

```
!c! delims= " was unexpected at this time.
.... (many more)
```

I don't understand how they work. Can someone explain it to me and give me a possible fix?
Also, is there any more errors in my code? If there is, can you point it out for me? Thanks.

I'm new to Batch btw (understood basic concepts & learnt mostly from [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/))

**EDIT:** This is the original code but easier to read (replace ampersands with new lines). Somehow this code works (...?) without the error. I still like to keep the original though.

```bash
Rem LINE 1 IN ORIGINAL CODE
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ERROR >%temp%\char1
echo a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ERROR >%temp%\char2
echo A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ERROR >%temp%\char3
set count=0 
set count2=0 
set useSpecialChar=0 
set char=15 
(if !useSpecialChar!==1 (set rnd=62) else (set rnd=92))

Rem LINE 2 IN ORIGINAL CODE (JUST A LABEL)
:gen

Rem: LINE 3 IN ORIGINAL CODE
(if %count%==%char% echo. 
    set /a count2+=1
    set count=0)
(if !count2!==5 pause >nul
    set count2=0)
set /a c=%random%%%62+1
set charno=1 
(if !c! gtr 10 set /a c-=10
    set charno=2)
(if !c! gtr 26 set /a c-=26
    set charno=3)
(for /f "tokens=%c% delims= " %%a in (%temp%\char%charno%) do (<nul set /p =%%a))
set /a count+=1
goto gen
```

Comment: The `FOR` command can never parse more than 31 tokens at a time. Depending on what random expands to you can in theory have the variable **c** be equal to more than 31.

Comment: In addition there is absolutely no benefit to be had in trying to squeeze everything into a single line. Please try to replace all of those ampersands with their proper line breaks so that other can read your code, (especially on small screens).

Comment: @Compo I edited the post. The reason I want to put all of them in a line is because I thought it would be funny to look at a mess that somehow actually works.

Comment: @Squashman see the edited post. I did make sure that `c` does not get past 31.

Comment: If you want a random number between two values it would be easier to do this: `SET /A result=%RANDOM% * 26 / 32768 + 1`

Comment: So, what you are telling us now, is that the fix I suggested, i.e. to replace the ampersands with line breaks, has solved your issue, but you still want to keep the original non working version! Also, what you've submitted is not technically just a replacement of those ampersands, you decided to remove some parentheses too! You do know that using ampersands to join multiple lines does not make your code any more efficient, and **is** the cause of your problem don't you?

Comment: Your error is caused because the `set /a c=%random%%%62+1` command is placed _in the same line_ that the `for /f "tokens=%c% ...` one that uses `%c%`. If you split these two commands on different lines, it should work. On the other hand, the `for /f "tokens=!c! ...` command (with delayed expansion on any part of the "options string") does _not_ work because the parser order.

Comment: @Aacini I moved `for /f ...` down a line and it worked. Thanks for the explanation. *my code is now 4 lines instead of 3 :(*

Comment: I feel I should mention BTW, that you need to be aware that using a space ampersand space sequence to join your commands is introducing trailing spaces. I left those in my [Edit] of your 'with line breaks' version. In this case they did not matter, but because you haven't yet got into the habit of using the recommended `set "var=val"` syntax, it could cause you issues in future, _much more than trailing spaces in `echo` lines_.

Comment: @Compo thanks for the tip. I knew `set "var=val"` but I usually use parenthesis-space-ampersand-space-parenthesis (for example `(set var1=smth) & (set var2=blabla)`) because it works just fine. I guess `set "var=val"` will come in handy in my future projects with batch when things get more complex.

Comment: @Aacini i saw your [post on dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428) 12 years ago that featured some auxiliary programs. I was interested in `getinput.exe` so I downloaded it to test. I wrote a simple batch file that does the following: execute `ver >nul` to reset `%errorlevel%`, call `getinput.exe` then `echo %errorlevel%`. I noticed a problem: after clicking for a few times, the `%errorlevel%` value seems to be bugged. I used the script to get the coordinates of the mouse click you included in the text file and saw that when it bugs, the row....

Comment: ...value of the mouse click keeps increasing by 3. Can you explain why it happens and perhaps fix it? I've been using your `cursorsize.exe` and `getkey.exe` and they're both really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: oh wait, my bad. sorry to have bothered you. I forgot that `echo` keeps creating new lines, so the command line moves down with it ;-; I thought it was a bug D:    Very helpful program though.

Comment: @ItsSuperPlayz: **`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`**